# Simple CSS Menu issues

Tags: html, css

I am using a menu system from this website
[CSS/Jquery Menu](http://codebrewery.blogspot.com/2011/01/memu-simple-css-javascript-jquery-menu.html)

In chrome the menu displays fine, but my main content(one textbox) is on the same line as the menu.

In IE 9 the Menu does not even display correctly.  The first element is rendered properly but the other two (and the sub menu) are displayed as normal hyperlinks
**Note in compatability mode, it sort of displays correctly, the shadow on the sub menu is missing but the elements are in the correct order and the textbox is still on the same line**

Is anyone willing to look at my Code and help me understand what I am doing incorrectly.  I consider my self versed in Html but not CSS where I believe the issue is.

Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Site.master.vb" Inherits="BudgetApplicationWeb.Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Styles/memu-0.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <style type="text/css" media="screen">


        pre { font-size: 0.6em; }

        .sprite-font_add { width: 16px; height: 16px; background:url(../famfamfam/css-sprite.png) no-repeat -0px -7216px; }
        .sprite-page_white { width: 16px; height: 16px; background:url(../famfamfam/css-sprite.png) no-repeat -0px -10048px; }

    </style>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
            <ul class="memu js-enabled">
                <li class="memu-root">
                    <a href="#">Accounts</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="has-children">
                            <li><a href="#"><div class="memu-icon sprite-page_white"></div>View Transactions</a></li>
                            <li><a href="New.aspx"><div class="memu-icon sprite-font_add"></div>New</a></li>                        
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="memu-root">
                    <a href="#">Budget</a>              
                </li>
                <li class="memu-root">
                    <a href="#">Settings</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Add Category</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Menu.css

```
.memu {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.memu ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 150px;

    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #333;
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #333;
}
.memu ul ul {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;

}
.memu a {
    background: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.98);
    border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    font: bold 12px/25px segoe ui,verdana,sans-serif;
    margin: 0 -1px -1px 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 139px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.memu .memu-icon {
    position: relative;
    width: 16px; 
    height: 16px; 
    margin: 4px 10px 0px 0px;
    float: left;
}

.memu li.memu-root > a {
    border-left: 0 !important;
    border-right: 0 !important;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent !important;
    background: transparent !important;
}

.memu li {
    float: left;
}
.memu li.has-children > a {
    background: url("arrow.png") no-repeat scroll #fff;
    background-position: 130px center;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.98);
}
.memu li:hover {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
.memu li:hover > a {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fafafa;
    color: #56789A;
}
.memu li:hover > ul {
    left: -20px;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 26px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.memu li:hover li:hover > ul {
    left: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.memu-current {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.98 !important) !important;
    }
```

New.aspx (with the textbox)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="New.aspx.vb" Inherits="BudgetApplicationWeb._New" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="t1"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Picture:
[image: Chrome Top IE9 Bottom]

HTML render as asked for:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head><title>

</title><link href="../Styles/memu-0.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

            <style type="text/css" media="screen">

            pre { font-size: 0.6em; }

            .sprite-font_add { width: 16px; height: 16px; background:url(../famfamfam/css-sprite.png) no-repeat -0px -7216px; }
            .sprite-page_white { width: 16px; height: 16px; background:url(../famfamfam/css-sprite.png) no-repeat -0px -10048px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="New.aspx" id="ctl01">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJNjI0NjY1NDA2ZGTedvbVstQSjEJlNsWGzH7rlBfvau1o6GnEDrB7goLkfg==" />
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAgKfvIywCgKp3sDPDCUOCLNtdSKEDWUr5o+bR23FLTplesWTeKeRUvhXZp/Y" />
</div>
        <div class="page">
                <ul class="memu js-enabled">
                    <li class="memu-root">
                        <a href="#">Accounts</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="has-children">
                                <li><a href="#"><div class="memu-icon sprite-page_white"></div>View Transactions</a></li>
                                <li><a href="New.aspx"><div class="memu-icon sprite-font_add"></div>New</a></li>                        
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="memu-root">
                        <a href="#">Budget</a>              
                    </li>

                    <li class="memu-root">
                        <a href="#">Settings</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Add Category</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
</div>
            <div class="main">
        <div>
        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$t1" type="text" id="MainContent_t1" />
        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        <div class="footer">
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please give us the HTML.  It's a lot easier to test than ASP.

Comment: i have given u html just replace it,it will work fine

Comment: put a jsfiddle that would be nice to encounter real problem

Comment: jsfiddle looks like it is putting the box on a second line because of wrapping but if you remove one of the menu items you see that the box is on the same line without the clear:left css http://jsfiddle.net/AVspN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
<li class="has-children">
 <li><a href="#"><div class="memu-icon sprite-page_white"></div>View Transactions</a></li>
<li><a href="New.aspx"><div class="memu-icon sprite-font_add">/div>New</a></li>
```

to this

```
<li class="has-children">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><div class="memu-icon sprite-page_white"></div>View Transactions</a></li>
<li><a href="New.aspx"><div class="memu-icon sprite-font_add"></div>New</a></li>                        
</ul>
                            </li>
```

Comment: this is not right method to use list sytle we cannot take a li under li, if we need to take li under another li we have to take ul and under that li

Comment: This made it work with Ie and chrome... I got rid of the li.has-children class and made it ul.has-children to save one level.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Chrome and Firefox are fixing whatever syntactical error you made and generating:

```
<div class="page">
                <ul class="memu js-enabled">
                    <li class="memu-root">
                        <a href="#">Accounts</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="has-children">
                                </li><li><a href="#"><div class="memu-icon sprite-page_white"></div>View Transactions</a></li>
                                <li><a href="New.aspx"><div class="memu-icon sprite-font_add"></div>New</a></li>                        

                            </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="memu-root">
                        <a href="#">Budget</a>              
                    </li>

                    <li class="memu-root">
                        <a href="#">Settings</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Add Category</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have solved it in the css is the line

```
.memu li {
float: left;
}
```

so I added a

```
.main {
 clear: left;
 }
```

And that works for everything except IE9.  Not sure if that is the best way to handle this issue.  Please continue to comment if this is incorrect.